# How to mock an Nhibernate.ISession Query<T>

Tags: c#, nhibernate, moq

```
static ContainerBuilder BaseSetupForMoq(EmptyInterceptor testInterceptor = null )
    {

        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        {

     var testrep= new MockHiber();

            containerBuilder.Register(c => testrep.SessionOpen())
                .As<ISession>()
                .InstancePerRequest();
        }
```

---

```
public ISession SessionOpen()
    {

        var session= new Mock<ISession>();
        session.Setup(x => x.Query<User>()).Returns(User);
        return session.Object;
    }
```

the line of code 'session.Setup(x => x.Query()).Returns(User);' is throwing error
Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: x => x.Query()

Now i have researched and found out that extension methods such as Query<> cannot be mocked and a wrapper should be used. But that approach also didn;t worked,

Would really appreciate if I can be helped here.

Comment: What is the question? It is unclear what you are asking as all that has been shown so far are statements

Comment: In the method test, i am trying to return the isession object but since the the Query<t> is extension method , it was throwing "Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: s => s.Query<TestUser>()". 
The line of code which threw error earlier was ' testsession.Setup(x => x.Query<TestUser>()).Returns(TestUser);'

Comment: so i wrote a helper class by following instructions in the few articles i found online...
 and now line of code 'return testsession.Object;' is throwing Cannot implicitly convert type 'ISessionLinq' to 'NHibernate.ISession'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Ok I get that but what is the desired behavior. What are you trying to test. Moq does not allow setup of extension methods. But if you know what the extension methods interacts with you could probably mock that. which would allow the extension to work when testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return `ISession`, while your Mock is of type `Mock<ISessionLinq>`. If you change it to `ISessionLinq`, it should work.

```
public ISessionLinq test()
```

Though you have to understand you are not mocking NHibernate here, what you mock is your own interface `ISessionLinq`

Comment: No..Problem is still there.. The  actual line of code is     Mock<ISessionLinq> testsession = new Mock<ISessionLinq>();

Comment: return testsession.Object;

Comment: I have followed this article http://jahav.com/blog/testing-nhibernate-queries-using-ienumerable/ and went through other answers..Can you please guide me towards correct approach

Comment: I have not worked much with NHibernate myself, but if you want to mock the data that it returns, I think you can mock this `ISession` interface directly and return any results in there. Though if you use this NHibernateLinqExtension to query your data, instead of `ISession` directly, that should do the trick as well. Or maybe this will work just fine for you if you just fix the return type :)

Comment: Try and avoid mocking types you don't own. You're making promises that someone else might not keep.